# the input file type image size restriction is not working

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-validate

Actually i tried with this url for jquery image file validation but its not working.could you please verify and advise me?

---

click here:  https://github.com/snyderp/jquery.validate.file

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
    <input type="file" name="example_file" name="example_file">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#upload_form")
        .validate({
            rules: {
                example_file: {
                    fileType: {
                        types: ["text", "gzip", "zip"]
                    },
                maxFileSize: {
                    "unit": "KB",
                    "size": 100
                },
                minFileSize: {
                    "unit": "KB",
                    "size": "10"
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what validation is not working? The size, the file type, ...?

Comment: pls see the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/h2nduLco/

Comment: You're missing a closing brace and failed to include the custom methods.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the extension so only including jquery and jquery.validate won't be enough. So also include the plugin by downloading the plugin. (I Know it's missing in the example)

Final solution should be something like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
    <input type="file" name="example_file" name="example_file">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.file.js"></script>
<script> $(function () {
    $("#upload_form")
        .validate({
            rules: {
                example_file: {
                    fileType: {
                        types: ["text", "gzip", "zip"]
                    },
                maxFileSize: {
                    "unit": "KB",
                    "size": 100
                },
                minFileSize: {
                    "unit": "KB",
                    "size": "10"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Testing the uploadfunction in jsfiddle is not the best idea, cuz it doesn't allow file uploads in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such rules called `fileType`, `maxFileSize` and `minFileSize` as part of the jQuery Validate plugin.  You would need to [write your own rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) *or maybe [you simply forgot to include the custom file uploading rules from GitHub that you referenced](https://github.com/snyderp/jquery.validate.file)*.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!--// need to include this one too //-->
<script src="jquery.validate.file.js"></script>
```

You also have a missing closing brace...

```
$("#upload_form").validate({
    rules: {
        example_file: {
            fileType: { 
                types: ["text", "gzip", "zip"]
            },
            maxFileSize: { 
                "unit": "KB",
                "size": 100
            },
            minFileSize: { 
                "unit": "KB",
                "size": "10"
            }
        } // <- THIS one was missing
    }
});
```

1. Include the plugin that adds the file-uploading methods.
2. Fix the missing brace.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/h2nduLco/3/**